# add buttons array in adapter using grid view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add Buttons array in grid view adapter. Please help me to run this programme.

```
 for (int index = 0; index < Item.length; index++) {
        myButton[index] = new Button(this); //initialize the button here
        myButton[index].setText(Item[index]);
        myButton[index].setWidth(120);
        myButton[index].setHeight(120);
        myButton[index].setId(index);
        //myButton[index].setTag(index);
       // scrViewButLay.addView(myButton[index]);
        myButton[index].setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(myButton[index]));
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myButton);
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? You need to specify what issue you're actually having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the ArrayAdapter class and override getView() to return the type of view you want for each item, a button in this case. You can then try  or use the type with no type parameter.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Comment: Thank u very much. Can u please provide me a simple example for this it would be really beneficial.

Comment: Button[] buttons = ...

and in getView()

    return buttons[i];